# Node.js source code can not search for a certain user id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongodb-query

I have seen source code as followings from an online doc.

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

Now I want to try query by user name, i.e. to change `collection.find({},{},function(e,docs)` into `collection.find({'username':'xxx'},{},function(e,docs)`

What I don't understand is `collection.find()({},{},function(e,docs){}` what is {} {} means, I tried to change it to `collection.find()({'username':'xxx'},{},function(e,docs)` but the result does not change, it still show query results for all users. And what is e and docs parameters and where their values come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find(<criteria>, <projection>, function(err, docs) {

});
```

The first argument is the **criteria** (Specifies selection criteria using query operators. To return all documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty document).

The second argument is the **projection** (Specifies the fields to return using projection operators. To return all fields in the matching document, omit this parameter).

The function is a callback where the first argument is an error, and the second is the resulting documents from the query.

More information can be found in the docs.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this has nothing to do with node.js or source code, but rather, the MongoDB client for node.js.